# AXL Python getLine using pattern instead of uuid does not work (CUCM 11.5)

Tags: python, suds, cucm

I'm struggling with getting for example line info via getLine using pattern instead of uuid. According to getLine AXL schema for CUCM 11.5 it should be possible to choose either uuid or pattern as lookup criteria. The python (2.7) module that I'm using is suds-jurko 0.6.

Base code is as follows:

```
from suds.client import Client
import ssl

wsdl = 'file:///C:/Users/xyz/Documents/axlplugin/schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl'
location = 'https://10.10.20.1/axl/'
username = '***'
password = '***'

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

client = Client(wsdl, location=location, username=username, password=password)
```

First of all, the proof that the pattern I want to use as a lookup string for getLine actually exists:

```
>>> line2 = client.service.listLine({'pattern': '1018'}, returnedTags={'description': ''})
>>> line2
(reply){
return =
(return){
line[] =
(LLine){
_uuid = "{1EC56035-6B5D-283A-4DF0-EFEFA01FCEFF}"
description = None
},
}
}
```

Then, I try getLine using uuid which works well:

```
>>> line5 = client.service.getLine('1EC56035-6B5D-283A-4DF0-EFEFA01FCEFF')
>>> line5
(reply){
return =
(return){
line =
(RLine){
_uuid = "{1EC56035-6B5D-283A-4DF0-EFEFA01FCEFF}"
pattern = "1018"
description = None
usage = "Device"
routePartitionName = ""
aarNeighborhoodName = ""

----Rest omitted for brevity---
```

Now, if I try to use pattern, not uuid, I have following error:

```
line6 = client.service.getLine({'pattern': '1018'}, {'routePartitionName': ''})

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 576, in invoke
soapenv = binding.get_message(self.method, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 109, in get_message
content = self.bodycontent(method, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\document.py", line 95, in bodycontent
add_param, self.options().extraArgumentErrors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\argparser.py", line 83, in parse_args
return arg_parser(args, kwargs, extra_parameter_errors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\argparser.py", line 108, in __call__
self.__process_parameters()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\argparser.py", line 299, in __process_parameters
self.__process_parameter(*pdef)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\argparser.py", line 294, in __process_parameter
self.__in_choice_context(), value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\document.py", line 86, in add_param
p = self.mkparam(method, pdef, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\document.py", line 130, in mkparam
return Binding.mkparam(self, method, pdef, object)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 225, in mkparam
return marshaller.process(content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\core.py", line 59, in process
self.append(document, content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\core.py", line 72, in append
self.appender.append(parent, content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\appender.py", line 88, in append
appender.append(parent, content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\appender.py", line 229, in append
Appender.append(self, child, cont)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\appender.py", line 168, in append
self.marshaller.append(parent, content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\core.py", line 71, in append
if self.start(content):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\literal.py", line 86, in start
raise TypeNotFound(content.tag)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'pattern'
```

Trying different syntax also gives error:

```
line6 = client.service.getLine('1018')
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 581, in invoke
result = self.send(soapenv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 619, in send
description=tostr(e), original_soapenv=original_soapenv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 670, in process_reply
raise WebFault(fault, replyroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Item not valid: The specified Line was not found'
```

Am I using incorrect syntax or it's actually not possible to use pattern however schema file states differently?

Additionally, I'm wondering how to extract only uuid value from for example listLine method, is it possible via python axl?

Answer (score 0):

In Suds, if memory serves me correctly, you can use keyword arguments for get and update requests.

For example:

`resp = client.service.getLine(routePartitionName='PT-ONCLUSTER', pattern='\+49301234567')`

if that doesn't work, try:

```
resp = client.service.getLine({'routePartitionName': 'PT-ONCLUSTER', 'pattern': '\+49301234567'})
```

Or better yet, check out python-zeep instead. It's much faster and better maintained than suds. Some example code with Zeep:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from zeep import Client
from zeep.cache import SqliteCache
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.exceptions import Fault
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from lxml import etree


disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

username = 'admin'
password = 'password'
# If you're not disabling SSL verification, host should be the FQDN of the server rather than IP
host = '10.1.1.1'

wsdl = 'file://C:/path/to/wsdl/AXLAPI.wsdl'
location = 'https://{host}:8443/axl/'.format(host=host)
binding = "{http://www.cisco.com/AXLAPIService/}AXLAPIBinding"

# Create a custom session to disable Certificate verification.
# In production you shouldn't do this, 
# but for testing it saves having to have the certificate in the trusted store.
session = Session()
session.verify = False
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

transport = Transport(cache=SqliteCache(), session=session, timeout=20)
history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport, plugins=[history])
service = client.create_service(binding, location)

def show_history():
    for item in [history.last_sent, history.last_received]:
        print(etree.tostring(item["envelope"], encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))

try:
    resp = service.getLine(pattern='1018', routePartitionName='')
except Fault:
    show_history()
```